# How to resolve Out Of Memory issue in production without increasing heap size

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Is there any way to resolve Out Of Memory issue in production environment without any downtime in production environment ?

Comment: And what’s causing this issue?

Comment: Are you caching any data, that would be the first place to look,

Comment: You have to check the Memory Leak issue. Take a memory dump and find out the issue.

Comment: Get the heap dump when the server is out of memory using jmap -dump:format=b,file=<file_name> <pid> or add this property to server startup args so that the heap dump is captured automatically when the server runs out of memory -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=<path to this heap dump file>.  More about this in https://dzone.com/articles/memory-analysis-how-to-obtain-java-heat-dump